# Calling radio button (click event) on changing date of jquery date picker not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

My Code For Jquery datepicker date change function

```
$(function() {
    $("#datepickernew").datepicker({
        minDate: '-0',
        maxDate: "+3M",
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            var dataString = 'changedate=' + dateText;
            alert(dataString);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://localhost/abc/abc.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(result) {
                    $('#showavialabletime').html(result);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

this ajax returning some radio button on the basis of date selected

like

```
<input id="foo2015-09-28-10-00-am" name="datetime" class="myradio" value="2015-09-28 10:00 am" type="radio">
<label for="foo2015-09-28-10-00-am" id="foo12015-09-28-10-00-am">10:00 am</label>
<input id="foo2015-09-28-10-15-am" name="datetime" class="myradio" value="2015-09-28 10:15 am" type="radio">
<label for="foo2015-09-28-10-15-am" id="foo12015-09-28-10-15-am">10:15 am</label>
```

and onselecting one radio option my jquery alert message

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[name=datetime]').on('change', function() {
        var date = $('input[name=datetime]:checked').val();
        alert(date);
    });
});
```

Without ajax response above give alert for selected option but after ajax call it does not give alert message..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's dynamically added , you need to use  **[event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#showavialabletime').on('change','input[name=datetime]', function() {
       var date=$('input[name=datetime]:checked').val(); 
       alert(date);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Pranav C Balan

Comment: @GhanshyamjiGupta : glad to help :)

Comment: @GhanshyamjiGupta : lern more about event delegation here http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: @GhanshyamjiGupta please suggest if instead of on .live would have been used. So I think it will work directly ...

Comment: @ParasmaniBatra : As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live(). ( Taken from http://api.jquery.com/live/ )